# Is the Hilbert parallelotope compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider the Hilbert space 
$$\ell^2=\{(a_n): \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2< \infty \}$$ 
and the subspaces 
$$H_j=\left \{(a_n)\in \ell^2: a_j \in [0,\dfrac{1}{j}] \right \}, j=1, 2, \cdots, $$
and the so called Hilbert parallelotope 
$$H=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty H_j=\prod_{n=1}^\infty [0,\dfrac{1}{n}]$$
the latter two are obvious closed in $\ell^2$. My question is: Is the Hilbert parallelotope $H$ compact? Further, does the subspace topology of $H$ inherited from $\ell^2$ coincide with the product topology on $\prod_{n=1}^\infty [0,\dfrac{1}{n}]$ as a product of the intervals $[0,\dfrac{1}{n}]$?

Comment: It is compact, but the two topologies are different.

Comment: You can just assume without loss of generality that $n=1$ right? In which case, Tychonoff tells you it is compact, but the standard basis of $\ell^2$ would give you a sequence without any convergent subsequence in the topology of $\ell^2$

Comment: To show compactness you can recursively pick subsequences so that you have convergence in every coordinate, and work a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{a^{(n)}\}$ be a sequence in $H$ such that $a^{(n)}\to a$ pointwise. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $N>0$ such that $\sum_{j>N}1/n^2<\varepsilon^2/8$. For $j\leq N$, we can choose $n_0$ such that $|a^{(n)}_j-a_j|<\varepsilon^2/\sqrt{2N}$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,N$ and all $n>n_0$.

So, for $n>n_0$,
$$
\|a^{(n)}-a\|_2^2=\sum_j|a^{(n)}_j-a_j|^2=\sum_{j\leq N}|a^{(n)}_j-a_j|^2+\sum_{j>N}|a^{(n)}_j-a_j|^2\\ \leq\sum_{j\leq N}\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4N}+2\sum_{j>N}|a^{(n)}_j|^2+|a_j|^2=\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+4\sum_{j>N}\frac1{j^2} \\
\leq\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+\frac{\varepsilon^2}2=\varepsilon^2.
$$
So $a^{(n)}\to a$ in $\ell^2$, i.e. the two topologies agree on $H$. In particular $H$ is compact in the $\ell^2$ topology.

Comment: Could you please explain why the above proof indicates the two topologies agree?

Comment: It shows that, in $H$, pointwise convergence of sequences implies $\ell^2$-convergence of sequences. The other implication always holds. Note that I'm using sequences but the exact same proof works for nets. So the two topologies agree.

Comment: A beautiful proof, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!